# не работает return на событии onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, submit

Здравия! У меня возникла интересная проблема:
Имеется

```
<form action="dashboard/index.php" onsubmit="check('pass')" method="post">
```

А так-же :

```
function check(pass) {
  if(document.getElementById(pass).value.length!==0){
      alert("true");
       return true;
  }else{
    alert("false");
    return false
  }
}
</script>
```

При этом при вызове alert будь то true ; будь то false : он всегда переключает уже на след. страницу. Мне крайне интересно почему.
Спасибо заранее. Ах , да.

```
      <input id="pass" placeholder="Ваш пароль" type="text">
```

Answer (score 3):

Считайте, что код в значении атрибута `onsubmit` - это тело функции. Эта функция должна что-то вернуть, если Вы хотите повлиять на поведение сабмита.

```
<form action="dashboard/index.php" onsubmit="return check('pass')" method="post">
```

Answer (score 2):

надо писать так:

```
<form action="dashboard/index.php" onsubmit="return check('pass')" method="post">
                                                ^----
```

---

```js
function check(pass) {
  if(document.getElementById(pass).value.length!==0){
      alert("true");
       return false;
  }else{
    alert("false");
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="dashboard/index.php" onsubmit="return check('pass')" method="post">
<input id="pass" placeholder="Ваш пароль" type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: не надо `pass` брать в кавычки, это входящий параметр

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych точно, не увидел аргумент  функции